# Which shape focusses rays to a single point?

Tags: geometric-optics

Which shape after refraction concentrates  monochromatic light rays parallel to a single focal point at origin inside a denser medium like glass?

Comment: you should specify monochromatic light since glass would focus different wavelengths at different focal points.

Comment: Do you mean a *point* or a *small volume*?     It is not possible to focus light to a *point*.

Comment: @garyp It is also not possible to have parallel, monochromatic light...

Comment: @garyp At microwave of larger wavelengths EM Waves are focussed to a point.

Comment: Can you provide a reference describing how microwaves can be focused to a point?

Comment: Thanks. Microwave parabolic antennas in L /C/Ku/Ka bands for example in a single unchanging medium. In physics yes we cannot have a mathematically idealized point, but concentration in areas small compared to aperture/wavelength  or as you say a small volume around focus can be considered . Text books in communication Engg e.g., Potter and Rusch.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved when the surface of the denser medium is defined by a parabola whose axis is parallel to the incident rays, and which is rotated about its axis to produce the surface.

More details on this can be found in almost any text on optics.  What you are asking about is a perfect single surface lens, which is closely analagous to a parabolic reflector:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_reflector

Comment: We are talking about refraction, not reflection.

Comment: @Narasimham Well observed.  See this link to learn about analogies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analogy